# Visual Studio remote Azure repository not updating

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am able to commit the changes to my local repository but am unable to push or sync and am unsure why this is the case.  From team explorer both Commit All and Push or Commit All and Sync don't fail, but the remote repository is not updated.

[image]

here is a shot of my remote repository

[image]

I was initially able to push everything but since then... nothing, push is never enabled and sync seems to only sync with the local repository, which is odd in itesef

Comment: What is the error? Have you tried it in the console if VS doesn't reveal that?

Comment: Like I said, there is no error, it just does not do anything.  No I have not tried it in the console, as I would like it to work as an integrated portion of visual studio.

Comment: Have you check the URL and the branch between Visual Studio and Azure devops? If yes, have you tried to push the code from git command line without VS?

Comment: the branches are the same the url does go to the correct repository.  What is the git command?  No where is this displayed in the Azure DevOps, or at least from what I can find.